# Error al hacer fetch a una ruta de la api NEXTJS

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, fetch, cors, nextjs

Tengo un componente en pages/profile/[profile].js en el cual quiero hacer una peticion fetch a la ruta pages/api/profile/[profile].js, pero al hacerlo me da un error 404

```html
//pages/profile/[profile].js
try {
                      const resp = await fetch('api/profile/username', {
                        method: 'PUT',
                        headers: {
                          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                          id: userF420._id,
                          fullname,
                        }),
                      })
                    } catch (error) {
                      console.error(error)
                    }
```

```html
// pages/api/profile/[profile].js

export const handler = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req.body.fullname)
    const { method, body } = req

    if (method === 'PUT') {
      if (body.fullname) {
        await UserSchema.findOneAndUpdate(
          { _id: body.id },
          { fullname: body.fullname }
        )
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Nombre actualizado' })
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error al actualizar el nombre' })
  }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar esto, no puedo hacer peticiones a mi backend por lo mismo

Comment: deberia de ser asi como lo tengo, en la pagina welcome tengo una llamad afetch a la url api/welcome y funciona correctamente

Comment: Ensaya poner la ruta con un / al inicio... porque sino será una ruta relativa a la ruta desde donde la llamas... `fetch('/api/profile/username', { ... })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YA ESTA RESUELTO! :D

Tenia el error de que estaba exportando mal el componente de la api
Tenia que ser exportado por defecto por ser una pagina de nextjs